# Error Parameter Creating user in AWS Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I iam trying to create an user with AWS Quicksight with Quicksight API in Lambda:

def registerUser():
nonlocal awsAccountId, email, quickSightIdentity

```
    logger.info(email)
    
    try:
    
        #Register the user
        quickSightIdentity.register_user(
            IdentityType ='QUICKSIGHT',
            Email = email,
            UserRole ='AUTHOR',
            AwsAccountId = awsAccountId,
            Namespace = 'default'
        )

    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception('Lambda registerUser function:'+str(e))
```

And i'm getting the following error:

{
"statusCode": 400,
"headers": {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
"Content-Type": "text/plain"
},
"body": ""Error: Lambda handler function:Before getDashboardList call: Lambda registerUser function:An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the RegisterUser operation: Invalid resource identifiers provided. Please check the documentation. ""
}

What can be wrong in this function? The email and awsAccountId values are ok.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a field for UserName when the IdentityType is QUICKSIGHT.

```
quickSightIdentity.register_user(
                IdentityType ='QUICKSIGHT',
                Email = email,
                UserRole ='AUTHOR',
                AwsAccountId = awsAccountId,
                Namespace = 'default',
                UserName: username
            )
```